# Change of variables in a partial differential equation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

How to convert the following partial differential equation (pde) 
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}=aV-as\frac{\partial V}{\partial s}-b^2s^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial s^2}$$
into a pde of the form
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=x^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+cx\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$
by some change of variables?
Here $a,b,c$ are constants. (A hint should be enough.)

Comment: @doraemonpaul, I think that's enough editing for a while. You are flooding the front page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hint**

If you send $t\mapsto -t$, it will fix the sign.

An exponential integrating factor factor of $e^{At}$ will get rid of the $aV$ term.

Then you just need to send $s\mapsto\lambda x$ and compute the correct scaling factors.

Comment: Thanks. I think the last step should be rescaling the time: $t_1=b^2t$.